# R Shiny: Formatting reactive data.frame from sql query

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to figure out how i can change type of the column after getting the data from reactive sql query...

for example when i fetch the data from database, some of the columns are characters, and i wish them to be factors. And some of the columns are numeric (which is correct) but i need them to be displayed as factors in datatable (for use in the datatable, as the column named is Tolerance, and tolerance cannot be filtered by range, it should be one single number).

Simple code:

```
library(ROracle)
library(shiny)
library(DT)


server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xx/K",username="user",password="pwd")
    tableList <- dbListTables(con,schema="K")

    updateSelectizeInput(session, "tabnames", server = TRUE, choices = tableList)

      sqlOutput <- reactive({
        sqlInput <- paste("select rownum * from K.",input$tabnames)
        dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput, stringsAsFactors = T)#it hasnt worked neither
      })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(sqlOutput(), server=TRUE, rownames=TRUE, filter="top", options=list(pageLength=10))

    session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })
  })

ui_panel <- 
  tabPanel("Test",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel( 
             ),
             mainPanel(
               selectizeInput("tabnames",label = "server side", choices = NULL),

               tableOutput("out"),
               tableOutput("table")
             )
           )
  )


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",ui_panel))

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

When i have tried simply:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

sqlOutput()$HOEHE_TOLP <- as.factor(sqlOutput()$HOEHE_TOLP)

datatable(sqlOutput(), server=TRUE, rownames=TRUE, filter="top", options=list(pageLength=10))})
```

It didnt work, and gave me an error:

```
Error in sqlOutput()$HOEHE_TOLP <- as.factor(sqlOutput()$HOEHE_TOLP) : 
  ungültige (NULL) linke Seite in Zuweisung
```

*`invalid (NULL) left side of assignment`

Any ideas how i can convert some columns to factors for reactive data frame?

Cheers

Comment: You can save the data frame locally in the reactive function and then invoke as.factor() on needed columns.

Comment: That might be tricky as there will be lots of users, that are going to use the app, second that filtered data is going to be quite big...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that because saving and returning the data frame into a variable is no different from what the reactive returns (a data frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Simply replace this expression:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(sqlOutput(), server=TRUE, 
  rownames=TRUE, filter="top", options=list(pageLength=10))
```

With:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  intermed <- sqlOutput()
  intermed$HOEHE_TOLP <- as.factor(intermed$HOEHE_TOLP)
  datatable(intermed) %>% formatStyle("RUND2_MITT", color = 'red', 
    backgroundColor = 'lightyellow', fontWeight = 'bold')
}, server=TRUE, rownames=TRUE, filter="top", options=list(pageLength=10))
```

Here is a self contained example:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("inst", "Instigate Reactive"),
  dataTableOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  data <- eventReactive(input$inst, {
    iris
  })

  output$test <- renderDataTable({
    set <- data()
    set$Sepal.Length <- as.factor(set$Sepal.Length)
    datatable(set) %>% formatStyle("Petal.Length", color = 'red', 
                                   backgroundColor = 'lightyellow',
                                   fontWeight = 'bold')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!It worked perfectly, but just one thing: When i used `%>%  formatStyle("RUND2_MITT",  color = 'red', backgroundColor = 'lightyellow', fontWeight = 'bold')` for datatable, it gave me an error: `Error in appendFormatter(x$options$rowCallback, columns, colnames, rownames,  : 
  You specified the columns: RUND2_MITT, but the column names of the data are`. Do You have any idea how i can implement `formatStyle`?